# How to add dynamic Header and Footer Data in PDF Generation using SuiteScript XML in NetSuite?

Tags: xml, pdf, netsuite, freemarker, suitescript

Is there a way to include specific data in both the header and footer of each page? When the document spans multiple pages, I want to display the sum of the previous page in the header of subsequent pages. Moreover, in the footer, I aim to show the sum of the amounts on the current page plus the sum from the previous page. How can I efficiently manage variables and logic across pages using SuiteScript in NetSuite? Is this posible with suitescript and freemarker

I'm using render module

```
var jsonData = {...mydata};
var aux = file.load("../FTL/template.xml");
var renderer = render.create();
renderer.templateContent = aux.getContents();
renderer.addCustomDataSource({
format: render.DataSource.OBJECT,
alias: "input",
data: {
data: JSON.stringify(jsonData),
},
});
stringXML = renderer.renderAsPdf();

const saveFile = (stringValue) => {
var fileAuxliar = stringValue;
var urlfile = "";   
nameReport = "Format.pdf";
var folderID = 12;

fileAuxliar.name = nameReport;
fileAuxliar.folder = folderID;

var fileID = fileAuxliar.save();

let auxFile = file.load({
 id: fileID,
 });    
 urlfile += auxFile.url;    
};

//template xml
<#assign data = input.data?eval >
<#assign company = data.company >
<#assign total = data.total >
<#assign movements = data.movements >
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE pdf PUBLIC "-//big.faceless.org//report" "report-1.1.dtd">
<pdf>
<head>
<meta name="title" value="Format10" />
<macrolist>
<macro id = "cabecera">
<table width="100%">
<tr>
<td align="center" style="font-size: 12px; font-family: Verdana, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; font-weight: bold; text-align:center;">${company.formato}</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td align="left" height="10px"> </td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td align="left" style="font-size: 12px; font-family: Verdana, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; font-weight: bold;">${company.period}</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td align="left" style="font-size: 12px; font-family: Verdana, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; font-weight: bold;">${company.id}</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td align="left" style="font-size: 12px; font-family: Verdana, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; font-weight: bold;">${company.name}</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td align="left" height="10px"> </td>
</tr>
</table>
</macro>
</macrolist>
</head>
<body background-color="white" font-size="8" size="A4-landscape" header = "cabecera" header-height="30mm" footer-height="10mm">
<table style="font-family: Verdana, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; width:100%" >
<tr>
<td width="25%" align = "center" style= "border:1px solid black; font-weight:bold; padding: 5px; text-align:center;">title 1</td>
<td width="25%" align = "center" style= "border:1px solid black; font-weight:bold; padding: 5px; text-align:center;">title 2</td>
<td width="50%" align = "center" style= "border:1px solid black; font-weight:bold; padding: 5px; text-align:center;">title3</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td width="25%" align = "center"></td>
<td width="50%" align = "left"></td>
<td width="25%" align = "center">"HERE GOES SUM OF PREVIUS PAGE"</td>
</tr>
<#list movements as key,mov>
<tr>
<td width="25%" align = "center">${mov.data1}</td>
<td width="50%" align = "left">${mov.data2}</td>
<td width="25%" align = "right">${mov.amount}</td>
</tr>
</#list>
<tr>
<td width="25%" align = "center"></td>
<td width="50%" align = "left"></td>
<td width="25%" align = "center">"HERE GOES SUM OF CURRENT PAGE"</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td width="10%" align="center" style= "border-top:1px solid black"></td>
<td width="10%" align="right" style="border-top:1px solid black; font-weight:bold;font-size: 11px;">TOTAL</td>
<td width="10%" align="right" style="border:1px solid black; font-weight:bold;font-size: 11px">${total.total}</td>
</tr>
</table>  
</body>
</pdf>
```